# Rails + Paperclip + S3 on Heroku upload error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to build an app where users can upload a profile picture.  I'm trying to use Paperclip and S3.

I've got it working on my local machine, but for some reason it doesn't work on Heroku.  Specifically, nothing is getting uploaded to S3, but there are also no errors being produced in the Heroku logs from Paperclip or S3.  Here's what I'm seeing in the logs:

```
2012-10-02T07:22:33+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Saving attachments.
2012-10-02T07:22:33+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] saving profile_pictures/2/original.jpg
2012-10-02T07:22:33+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] saving profile_pictures/2/thumb.jpg
2012-10-02T07:22:33+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] saving profile_pictures/2/medium.jpg
2012-10-02T07:22:33+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] saving profile_pictures/2/large.jpg
```

Here's what my s3.yml file looks like:

```
development:  
  access_key_id: XXXXXXX
  secret_access_key: XXXXXXX
  bucket: dev-bucket

test:
  access_key_id: XXXXXXX
  secret_access_key: XXXXXXX
  bucket: test-bucket

production:
  access_key_id: XXXXXXX
  secret_access_key: XXXXXXX
  bucket: prod-bucket
```

Anyone have an idea why this works on my dev machine but not on Heroku?  I'm perplexed by the lack of an error...

Comment: what do the paperclip options for for profile pictures model look like?

Comment: Could you mention which version of Rails you are running too?

Comment: Could you add your Gemfile shows related gems?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the environment variables using Heroku Toolbelt?

```
$ heroku config:set AWS_BUCKET=**BUCKET NAME**
$ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=***GET FROM AMAZON AWS***
$ heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=***GET FROM AMAZON AWS***
```

For this to work you would have to set:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```